# Wordpress: wp_update_post returns Error "Allowed memory size exhausted"

Tags: php, wordpress, out-of-memory

After the call of **wp_update_post($my_post)** I checked memory_get_usage(). With every call in a post update inside a foreach loop the memory usage is getting higher and higher.

Here are the outputs from **echo memory_get_usage();** which I did after wp_update_post():
1st call= 72923956
2nd call= 89410604
3rd call= 105152440
4th call= 120900116
5th call= 136651592
6th call= 152432716
7th call= 168178896
and then...
**Fatal error: *Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15728640 bytes) in .../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1196***

My question is:
Is there a possibility of flushing the memory, delete the content of the $my_post arrays which I built for **wp_update_post()**? By the way: The size of the arrays are appx 1000 characters each...

Here is a generalized code. You can search for "wp_update_post" to find the line with the memory problem.

Thanx for helping,
Mat

```
<?

function event_sync_doit() {

    $limit = $_POST['limit'];   // 1-1500
    $start = $_POST['start'];   // 0-1500
    $range = $_POST['range'];   // 1-100
    $end = min ( $start + $range , $limit );

    $string = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/party/api/json/?limit=".$limit);
    $json=json_decode($string,true);

    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {

        $event_id = $json['partylist'][$i][id];

        // ######### DELETED PART #########
        // Here we have a lot of variable assignments 
        // ######### DELETED PART #########

        if ( ($event_id>0) ) {

            // READ XML FROM example.com API
            $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.example.com/party/xml/'.$event_id); // or exit();

            // ######### DELETED PART #########
            // Here we have a lot of variable assignments 
            // ######### DELETED PART #########

            // SET FLYER 

            $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );

            $flyerfull_url = $xml->party[0]->{'flyerfull-url'};
            $flyersmall_url = $xml->party[0]->{'flyersmall-url'};                   
            $flyer_title = $start_date." - ".$partyname;

            if ( ($post_thumbnail_id > 0) AND ($post_thumbnail_id != 14072)) {
                // there is already a a standard post thumbnail with id 14072
            } else if ($flyerfull_url != "") {

            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $image_data = file_get_contents($flyerfull_url);
            $filename = basename($flyerfull_url);

            if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
                $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
                }
            else {
                $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
                }

            file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => $flyer_title,
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

            } else {    
                // set placeholder picture
                set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, "14072" );
            }

            // WRITE CONTENT HTML 

            if ( intval($lat) > 0 AND intval($lon) > 0 ) {
                $map_info = "<br><br><i>Scroll down for location map</i>";
            }
            else {
                $map_info = "";
            }

            // ######### DELETED PART #########
            $out = "COMPLETE STRING OF CONTENT - APPX 1000-2000 CHARACTERS EACH ENTRY";
            // ######### DELETED PART #########

            // -----------------
            // LINK URLS
            // -----------------
            $out = preg_replace_callback(
            '/((https?:\/\/)(www\.)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))([^<\/\?\s]+)[^<\s]*/',
            function ($matches) {

            switch($matches[6]){

                // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                case 'facebook.com':
                $graph_url = str_replace("//www.","//graph.",url_trim($matches[0],"http://"));

                $alter_error_handler = set_error_handler("mush_ErrorHandler");
                $seite = file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context);
                restore_error_handler();

                $graph = json_decode($seite, true);

                if ($graph["id"] > 0 AND $graph["gender"] = "") {
                    $return = "<br>[dpSocialTimeline skin=\"light\" total=\"2\" items=\"{'name':'facebook_page','data':'".$graph["id"]."','limit':'20'}\" showFilter=\"0\" showLayout=\"0\" itemWidth=\"47%\"]<br>[su_spacer]";
                    }
                else if ($graph["name"]) {
                    ($graph["name"] == "") ? $fb = "" : $fb = " of ".$graph["name"];
                    $return = "<a href=\"" . url_trim($matches[0],"http://") . "\">Facebook Profile". $fb ."</a><br>[su_spacer]";
                    }
                else {
                    $return = "<a href=\"" . url_trim($matches[0],"http://") . "\">Facebook Profile</a><br>[su_spacer]";
                }
                return $return;

                // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                case 'soundcloud.com':
                $alter_error_handler = set_error_handler("mush_ErrorHandler");         
                $seite = file_get_contents("http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=".url_trim($matches[0],"http://")."&client_id=c16efb34d50753daa59a5b6e9ef7ab44", false, $context);
                restore_error_handler();
                $json = json_decode($seite, true);  
                return "<br>[iframe src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//".url_trim($json['uri'],"")."&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;visual=true\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450\"]<br>[su_spacer]"; 

                // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                case 'example.com':
                return "" . $matches[0] . "";

                // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
                default:
                return "<a href=\"" . url_trim($matches[0],"http://") . "\">".url_trim($matches[0],"")."</a>";
                }
            },
            $out);
            $out = str_replace("<br />","<br>",$out);
            $out = str_replace("/>","",$out);


            // --------------------
            // GOOGLE MAPS 
            // --------------------

            if ( intval($lat) > 0 AND intval($lon) > 0 ) {
            $out = str_replace("{{LOCATIONMAP}}", "
            <tr>
            <td class='party_head'> Map </td>
            <td class='party_info'> [su_gmap width='540' height='500' responsive='yes' address='". $lat . "," . $lon . "']</td>
            </tr>
            ", $out);
            } else {
            $out = str_replace("{{LOCATIONMAP}}", "", $out);
            }

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // <<< END CREATE CONTENT
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

            } else {

            $wp_post = NULL;
            echo "<p> No example ID found !!! </p>";
        }


        if ( $wp_post ) {

        // Update Party entry
        $my_post = array(
        'ID'            => $post_id,
        'post_title'    => $nameParty,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_content'  => $out,
        'post_author'   => 2,
        'post_category' => array(118)
        );

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Update the post into the database
        echo memory_get_usage()."<br>";
        print_r($my_post);
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        wp_update_post( $my_post ); 
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        echo memory_get_usage()."<br>";
        $base_url = get_site_url();
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

        echo "<p> UPDATE PARTY ENTRY (<a href='$base_url?p=$post_id'>$post_id</a>) $sort_records <br>
        <a href='http://www.example.com/$event_id' target='_blank'><b>$nameParty</b></a><br>
        $sub_head </p>";
        } else {

        // Create post object
        $my_post = array(
        'post_name'     => $event_id,
        'post_title'    => $nameParty,
        'post_content'  => $out,
        'post_author'   => 2,
        'post_date'       => $dateCreated,
        'post_date_gmt' => $dateCreated,
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_category' => array(118)
        );
        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
        // $post_id = mush_get_post_id_by_name($event_id);
        echo "<p> CREATE PARTY ENTRY (<a href='$base_url?p=$post_id'>$post_id</a>) $sort_records <br>
        <a href='http://www.example.com/$event_id' target='_blank'><b>$nameParty</b></a><br>
        $sub_head </p>";
        }

        if ( $meta_event_id == $event_id OR $meta_event_id == "" OR $meta_event_id == NULL) {

            delete_post_meta( $post_id, "event_id");
            add_post_meta( $post_id, "event_id", $event_id );

            delete_post_meta( $post_id, "sub_head");
            add_post_meta( $post_id, "sub_head", $sub_head );

            delete_post_meta( $post_id, "sort_records");
            add_post_meta( $post_id, "sort_records", $sort_records );

            if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, "geo_location", TRUE )) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, "geo_location");
            add_post_meta( $post_id, "geo_location", $geo_location );
            }

        } else {

            return "example ID <> example META INFO. PLEASE CHECK ID ".$event_id." / META-ID ".$meta_event_id;
        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: I have added a generalized code now. I cutted out extensive variable declarations. You can search for "wp_update_post" to find the line with the memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact reason but you can try to unset `$xml` variable once the loaded file has been processed, similarly try removing large variables( file_get_contents returns ) when no longer in use. This could lower the memory requirement for each `for` loop.